# Get id of asp:checkbox inside a datalist using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

Code below hides table row based on checkbox checked state.
I have been unable to target the id of an asp:checkbox because of the way they render.

**CODE** (Table wrapped in datalist)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cb" CssClass="css" RunAt="Server"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row"><td></td</tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#<%= dl.ClientID %> #<%= cb.ClientID %>").change(function(){
    var hide = this.checked ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    $('.row').css('display', hide);
});
```

**SOLUTIONS**

```
$("#<%= dl.ClientID %> input:checkbox").change
```

*(Works but does not explicitly target a unique checkbox)*

```
$("#<%= dl.ClientID %> .css").change
```

*(Does not work because asp:checkbox class is attatched to a wrapped span tag)*

```
$("#<%= dl.ClientID %> #<%= cb.ClientID %>").change
```

*(Does not work because asp:checkbox id renders suffux of **_0** the checked state)*

**THE ANSWER**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" RunAt="Server" onclick="hide();"/>

function hide(){
    $('.row').toggle()
};
```

Comment: Are there multiple checkboxes like that on your page

Comment: Do you really need the ID? Can't you use `$("table td input:checkbox.css")` or something?

Comment: I have several checkboxs and each needs to hide different rows.

Comment: you could try jquery wildcard selector: $("[id^=" + #<%= cb.ClientID %>" + "]")

Comment: @DreamTeK -- Use an instance of `this`

Comment: Does this mean there is no clear cut way to get the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that the focus is always on unobtrusive javascript, but you always have the option to add the onclick attribute to the checkbox if you can't figure out a better solution.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" CssClass="css" RunAt="Server" onclick="callfunction(this);/>
```

Comment: Microscopic solution thanks to your idea. Thanks @Javalsu. (see above) for Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the ClientIDMode to Static.  This sets the ClientID to the value of the ID.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" ClientIDMode="Static" RunAt="Server" onclick="hide()" />

function hide() {
    $('#cb').toggle();
}
```